# Android SimpleAdapter change element style

Tags: android, coding-style, textview

I got a list of element displayed with a SimpleAdapter that gets the list of element to display.
The element in the list of object (the one that I pass to the SimpleAdapter) have a field that I want to use to differentiate the style of elements (elments are TextView) to display but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Jaxer

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to subclass Adapter (or one of its subtypes) and do something along the lines of this in the `getView` method:

```
TextView row;
// Recycle an already-inflated view if possible
if (convertView == null) {
     row = (TextView) View.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getContext());
} else {
    row = (TextView) convertView;
}
SomeModel myItem = getItem(pos);
if (getItem(pos).displayFunky()) { //or whatever object condition you want to check
    row.setTextColor(Color.RED)
} else {
    row.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
}

row.setText(myItem.getDisplayText());

return row;
```

You could also have a custom Adapter with multiple View types, but this is a simple enough case that I probably wouldn't bother. Also see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134875/android-listactivity-row-color-based-on-object-state). You should also check out sample code for adapters (here's [one from NPR](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/trunk/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/NewsListAdapter.java), for example) and a more complex multiple-views-in-an-adapter [tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296). You should also definitely check out the inimitable Romain Guy's presentations on ListViews at Google I/O [2009](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) and [2010](http://www.google.com/intl/ja-JP/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) - they'll save you hours of heartache, confusion, pain, and performance-tweaking.